# Global variable is empty if 2 similar xls files with same macro are opened

Tags: vba, excel

There is macro in Excel which was already written and there was bug reported on this and I have to fix this. Initial investigations are below...
There is `ABC.xls` file which has the `macro`.

Now, the macro has a `sub` named `changeTheCode` which is getting called when I press `Ctrl + M`.

This sub will open a `Open File Dialog` where the user can choose a CSV file. The path of the CSV file I am storing in a global variable declare outside of all the function...

```
Public txtFileNameAndPath As String
```

This global variable will be used to save the changes into the CSV file when the user closes the excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call saveUnicodeCSV
    Call deleteXLS
End Sub
```

I use this `ABC.xls` file for opening a `ABC123.CSV` file.

I use this `DEF.xls` (a copy of ABC.xls) file to open `DEF123.CSV` file. But when I open the `DEF123.CSV` using `Ctrl + M`, the sub `changeTheCode` of the `ABC.xls` is getting called and the global variable `txtFileNameAndPath` of `DEF.xls` is empty and when I close the Excel, things are not getting saved because of this.

[image]

Code where the global variable is getting set.

```
Public txtFileNameAndPath As String
Sub CodePageChange()
    Dim SheetName As Worksheet
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim sheetName1 As String
    Dim tabSheetName As String

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        '....
        '....
        '....
        If .Show = True Then
          txtFileNameAndPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "Please start over.  You must select a csv file."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
```

Inputs on how to handle this will help me a lot.

**Note:** The Excel containing macro will be given to customer. Hence I cannot ask customer to do some registry tweaks to open the Excel in separate instance.

Thanks.

Comment: are both files opened under the same instation of excel?

Comment: Yes they are opened in the same instance of excel.

Comment: An easy workaround: use separate instances of Excel

Comment: Maybe you can try Application.Run with specifing from which workbook you want to run macro

Comment: You need to show the code where you set/access the global variable.

Comment: Use a different hotkey for the two different workbooks! Macros have a scope.

Comment: @Absinthe: The excel with macro will be given to customers. I cannot give 2 excel files. The same excel file with macro will be used by customer to open many CSV files. But they are unable to copy and paste between the CSV's once they open it in excel.

Comment: @helpME1986: The macro is called by a hot key Ctrl + M, and the same excel (copies of this excel in different folder)(with the macro) is used to open different CSV files. Please suggest.

Comment: @Vegard: I used the approach of opening the excle in separate instance by 'Excel options' > 'advanced' tab > 'general' > check "Ignore other applications that use 'Dyanamic Data Exchange (DDE)'". But this is giving error "There was a problem sending the command to the program." when I double click to open the excel containg the macro.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I have added the code. Thanks.

Comment: It may be easier to debug if you include `Thisworkbook.Name` in your **Open File Dialog**

Comment: Awwww No bounty :'(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem I think is that when you bind the same macro names to a Shortcut Key, the first book that is opened will be assigned to that shortcut key.

A work around would be to make another macro to call the right macro based on the workbook name. This might require you to replace some of the Workbooks and Worksheets to ActiveWorkbook or ActiveWorksheet. But please try it out first.

This is just example code I tried out but please edit it to your needs. I tried it by making two files a.xlsm and b.xlsm. difference is a.xlsm has msgbox "a" in first line and b.xlsm has msbox "b" in the first line. You check by opening a.xlsm first then b.xls. Then assign the same shortcut key. You will see that when you run Ctrl+M in b.xlsm that the macro that will be run will be in a.xlsm with msgbox "A" but then it will call the correct macro in b.xlsm.

**Short Answer**

This code makes use of `Application.Run` which runs the macro from a specific workbook. create a helper macro that will check filename then append macro name.

So when you ctrl+m, regardless which workbook run_code is run from, it will go back to activeworkbook and run the macro, in this case plaster, from that workbook. Also it will populate the Public Variable with the activeworkbook value.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm some samples of application.run

**By far the easiest solution for you just add Caller Macro**

Caller Macro:

```
Sub call_changeTheCode() ' add to all workbooks, that have changeTheCode macro then assign to Ctrl + m

Application.Run ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!changeTheCode"

End Sub
```

Proof of concept, not your actual code, use above Caller Macro:

```
Public varvar As String
Sub run_code() 'assignt to shortcut key CTRL+M both macros in a.xlsm and b.xlsm
MsgBox "a" ' to test create another workbook and change this to b
file_path = ActiveWorkbook.Path 'just to check path
file_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'gets the file name
MsgBox file_path 'msgbox the file_path
MsgBox file_name 'msgbox the file_name
MsgBox file_name & "!plaster" 'msgbox the file name plus macro name, in your instance it would be "ABC.xlsm'!macro_name" please note the format
Application.Run file_name & "!plaster"

End Sub

Sub plaster() 'this is the test macro that will show correct macro in workbook is called
varvar = ActiveWorkbook.Name
MsgBox "hi this is workbook " & varvar

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh you beauty! Wonderfully compact.

Comment: @fcsr: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand it properly, user has `DEF.xls` as a top-level workbook, hence equal to `ActiveWorkbook`. Then my idea is to add new sheet to this workbook with very unique name, like "zZzVBAdatazZz" and make it very hidden (set `Sheets("zZzVBAdatazZz").Visible = xlVeryHidden`), so user can't unhide it with menu commands. When the macro is run you can store the path to `DEF123.CSV` in this sheet, let's say in cell `A1` (`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("zZzVBAdatazZz").Range(A1) = .SelectedItems(1)`). In your `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` check if there is a value in `Sheets("zZzVBAdatazZz").Range(A1)`. If so, take it and store in variable (it can be local now), delete value in `A1` and pass the path to `saveUnicodeCSV`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem, I believe the heart of the problem is that a workbook's global object is not really global across the whole application space.  Hereafter I write global as "global" to highlight this misnoma.

I believe your macro will always run from one place, so how to scope a "global" variable for each workbook and yet still reach it from another workbook's code base.

My solution would be to use the `ThisWorkbook` module as the place to house the "global" variable.  So in the `ThisWorkbook` module place the following code

```
Option Explicit

Public NJMRGlobalVar As Variant
```

then in the module of your macro code you will need a function to test if a given workbook supports/exports this new "global" variable.  So something like this ( given along with unit test)

```
Private Function WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar = False
    Else
        Dim vTest As Variant
        vTest = CVErr(xlErrName)
        'Requires VBA IDE->Tools->Options->General->Error Trapping->Break on Unhandled Errors
        On Error Resume Next
        vTest = CallByName(wb, "NJMRGlobalVar", VbGet)

        Dim lSaveError As Long
        lSaveError = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar = (lSaveError = 0)
    End If

End Function

Private Sub TestWorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar()

    Debug.Assert WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar(ThisWorkbook) = True

    Dim wbUnsuitable As Excel.Workbook
    Set wbUnsuitable = Workbooks.Item("VBA Fileshare.xlsm") '*<---- different for you!

    Debug.Assert WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar(wbUnsuitable) = False

End Sub
```

Final step is to rewrite your code not in terms of ThisWorkbook but either ActiveWorkbook or acquiring the target workbook with Application.Workbooks.Item("foo.xlsm").  So here is some code (which works on ActiveWorkbook).

```
Sub CodePageChange()
    Dim SheetName As Worksheet
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim sheetName1 As String
    Dim tabSheetName As String

    If Not WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar(ActiveWorkbook) Then
        MsgBox "Currently Active Workbook not a suitable candidate for that macro."
    Else

        Dim wbGlobalVarEnabled As Excel.Workbook
        Set wbGlobalVarEnabled = ActiveWorkbook

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

        With fd
            '....
            '....
            '....
            If .Show = True Then
                wbGlobalVarEnabled.NJMRGlobalVar = .SelectedItems(1)
            Else
                MsgBox "Please start over.  You must select a csv file."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

So now you have a "global" variable per workbook which is freely accessible from one code simply by acquiring a reference to an Excel.Workbook.  This works because Excel.Workbook does not forbid extensibility in the interface meaning extra methods and properties can be added (but not all workbooks will support them hence you a function to detect, e.g `WorkbookHasNJMRGlobalVar` above).

Please post feedback if not enough and I will amend, I have 99/100 on VBA questions I would like to earn my bronze VBA badge :)

EDIT: reading your profile you have C/C++ skills so I can go further in low-level explanation as to how this works.  In the type library for Excel the "nonextensible" IDL keyword decorates most interfaces forbidding extra methods and properties but this is missing from `interface _Workbook` so you can.  Here is a screenshot from OleView.exe

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A unique shortcut can only be assigned to a single procedure in a workbook.
Setting the same shortcut a second time overrides the previous assignment.

To handle the same shortcut in different workbooks, either assign the shortcut when the workbook is activated :

```
' ThisWorkbook '

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
  Application.OnKey "^m", "CodePageChange"
End Sub

' Module '

Public Sub CodePageChange()
  MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Or handle the callback in the workbook which receives it and then call the procedure on the targeted workbook:

```
' ThisWorkbook '

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnKey "^m", "OnHotkeyCtrlM"
End Sub

' Module '

Public Sub OnHotkeyCtrlM()
  Application.Run "'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!CodePageChange"
End Sub

Public Sub CodePageChange()
   MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

use custom property as a global variable

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

End Sub


Sub changeTheCode()

    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="xyz", LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:=ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("xyz")

End Sub
```

Comment: cool! at least cool if you want persistence across saves/sessions, mind you one could just write to a cell on a sheet for persistence.

Comment: @SMeaden, you could delete the property in the beforeClose sub if you do not want it there from one session to next.  it is just a value that is attached to the workbook itself and is unique to each workbook

Answer (score 1):

I agree with S Meaden, you cannot have a Global variable across several workbooks without specifying the workbook where the "global" variable is stored.

Another approach:
In the Excel file with the macro where the setting of the "global" variable is done:
Replace the setting with

```
Shell ("Cmd.Exe /C SetX txtFileNameAndPath thePath")
```

Replace thePath with the actual path or value.
After this macro is run you can run your Excel files and retrieve the true global value through

```
txtFileNameAndPath = Environ("txtFileNameAndPath")
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the global variable into the `ThisWorkbook` class module.

```
Public txtFileNameAndPath As String

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print Me.Name & ":" & txtFileNameAndPath
End Sub
```

Then in the procedure `CodePageChange` loop through all the workbooks and check using `ActiveWorkbook.Name` which global variable should be used. HTH

```
If .Show = True Then
  Dim w As Workbook
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each w In Workbooks
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = w.Name Then
        w.txtFileNameAndPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Exit For
    End If
  Next w
  On Error GoTo 0
Else
    MsgBox "Please start over.  You must select a csv file."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: very similar to mine below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464200/global-variable-is-empty-if-2-similar-xls-files-with-same-macro-are-opened/45545505#45545505

Comment: @SMeaden I haven't read all the other answers, so I apologize if I stole your idea.

Answer (score 0):

User-friendly workaround: Ditch the keyboard short-cut and add either a CommandButton to a worksheet or Custom Ribbon Tab to the workbook to call the procedure. They're guaranteed to call the procedure from their own workbook and easier for users.